# how to create a python package created using pybind?

Tags: python, c++, package, pybind11, xtensor

I created a miniconda environment using the following command:

```sh
conda create -n build_a_python_cpp_module xtensor-python -c conda-forge
```

Activated the environment and created a cookiecutter project for x-tensor (a C++ library for fast array computations like NumPy) in the project folder.

```
pip3 install cookiecutter
cookiecutter https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor-python-cookiecutter.git
```

After the project was created, I wrote a simple program to count the commas and new lines in a file in both C++ and python to compare the performance difference.

I bound the function in C++ using pybind11 and ran

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Importing the package and running the C++ method inside it using the python binding works but I want to know:

What should I do to be able to package it and transfer the code to another machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to run `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. This will create a wheel that you can upload on pypi.

You can test if it works with `pip install dist/name_of_your_wheel` before uploading it.

Let me know if you encounter any issue